# Is there any shorter way of writing this code?

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I am extremely new to programming, currently just messing around with console apps. I've created a few things like a login screen and a currency converter but that was with aid from teachers. Never done anything by myself.

I'm wondering if there's any better/shorter way of writing this?
Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim x As String
    Dim Y As String
    Dim yes As String
    Dim no As String
    x = "Please enter your name:"
    Y = "Please enter 'Y' or 'N'"
    yes = "Y"
    no = "N"
    Console.WriteLine(x)
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to continue?")
    yes = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine(Y)
    If yes = "Y" Then
        Console.WriteLine("You selected to continue")
    Else
        If no = "N" Then
            Console.WriteLine("You selected to exit")
            Environment.Exit(0)
        End If
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("TEXT HERE") 'Text here as I don't know what to put next yet
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.ReadLine() 'Just put this here so it doesn't exit straight away
End Sub
```

I had declared some variables just to try it out rather than just have Console.WriteLine("TEXT") constantly. I'm just trying to find ways of doing things.
I just ran the code again and saw that it's case sensitive to the user input, how would I go about having it be either Y or y and N or n?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its asking for a review. Please see https://www.codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name:")
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to continue?")

    Do
        Dim selectYN As String = Console.ReadLine()

        If selectYN.ToUpper = "Y" Then
            Console.WriteLine("You selected to continue")
            Exit Do
        ElseIf selectYN.ToUpper = "N" Then
            Console.WriteLine("You selected to exit")
            Environment.Exit(0)
            Exit Do
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter 'Y' or 'N'")
        End If
    Loop

    Console.WriteLine("TEXT HERE") 'Text here as I don't know what to put next yet
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.ReadLine() 'Just put this here so it doesn't exit straight away
End Sub
```

The code is much more minified than your code. I added also a loop until the user added a valid answer for the yes/no question. The user have to enter one of the following values to break the loop: `n, N, y, Y`. If the value is not valid the question appears again to give himn a chance to enter a new value again.

> *How would I go about having it be either Y or y and N or n?*

In this case you have the possibility to convert the letter `toLower` or `toUpper`. In the example above `toUpper` is used to check against `N` and `Y`.